# How to get SP 2013 site taxonomy data in SP 2010 site [JSOM/REST]

Tags: 2013, 2010, rest, taxonomy, jsom

I am working on a javascript function for SP 2010 site where i need to fetch some data (Taxonomy) from a 2013 SharePoint site. **Is there any way that i can get the SP 2013 site taxonomy data in SP 2010 application using JSOM or REST (JS)?** Both the sites are in the same network. 

The below code is throwing an error at `context = SP.ClientContext(2013 site URL);`

Error - *Argument Exception. Value doesn't fall within the expected range. Paramenter name : serverRelativeUrl*

**SP 2010 code -**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var scriptbase = 2013 site URL/_layouts/15/";


$.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Taxonomy.js", function () {

context = SP.ClientContext(2013 site URL);

getTaxonomyData();

});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant connect to an other SharePoint-Site than the local one using JSOM. The Reason it internally connects to the SharePoint-Services of your current Site and then tries to find the Site on that Server, which is not the case.

You could try accessing the Remote-Sites Rest-Webservices using plain Javascript, but you have to enable Cross-Origin-Ressource-Sharing on the remote-Server first (otherwise your browser won´t let you call the remote Services)

Comment: Thanks Leopold. Is it possible to get taxonomy data using REST in SP 2013 ?

Comment: No sorry, my mistake, there seems to be no rest-Service for taxonomy, just  the JSOM. However, you could implement your own webservice, residing on the requested Server and delivering the data you expect.